# How to get data from API using MatAutocomplete? (angular)

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular and I'm trying to fetch a local api `(localhost:4200/office_keys)` to show the items on an mat-autocomplete this way:

**HTML:**

```html
 <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <mat-label>Office Key</mat-label>
          <input matInput [formControl]="control" [matAutocomplete]="office_keys" #desc required />
          <mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let keys of office_keys" [value]="keys">
              {{ keys }}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-autocomplete>
        </mat-form-field>
```

**(part of) TS:**

```js
filteredOptions: Observable<any[]>;
office_keys: Observable<OfficeKey>;
saveForm: FormGroup;
control = new FormControl();


constructor(private officeKeyService: OfficeKeyService) {
             
}

this.saveForm = new FormGroup({
  office_key: new FormControl("", [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(3),
        Validators.maxLength(255),
      ]),
})


get office_key() {
    return this.saveForm.get("office_key.description");
  }


ngOnInit(): void {
    this.filteredOptions = this.control.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(""),
      debounceTime(200),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap((value) => this.filter(value || ""))
    );
  }

filter(val: string): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.officeKeyService.read().pipe(
      map((response) =>
        response.filter((option) => {
          return (
            option.description.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) === 0
          );
        })
      )
    );
  }
```

**Service:**

```js
baseUrl = "http://localhost:8000/office_keys";

 create(office_key: OfficeKey): Observable<OfficeKey> {
    return this.http.post<OfficeKey>(this.baseUrl, office_key).pipe(
      map((obj) => obj),
      catchError((e) => this.errorHandler(e))
    );
  }

  read(): Observable<OfficeKey[]> {
    return this.http.get<OfficeKey[]>(this.baseUrl).pipe(
      map((obj) => obj),
      catchError((e) => this.errorHandler(e))
    );
  }

  readById(id: number): Observable<OfficeKey> {
    const url = `${this.baseUrl}/${id}`;
    return this.http.get<OfficeKey>(url).pipe(
      map((obj) => obj),
      catchError((e) => this.errorHandler(e))
    );
  }

  update(office_key: OfficeKey): Observable<OfficeKey> {
    const url = `${this.baseUrl}/${office_key.id}`;
    return this.http.put<OfficeKey>(url, office_key).pipe(
      map((obj) => obj),
      catchError((e) => this.errorHandler(e))
    );
  }

  delete(id: number): Observable<OfficeKey> {
    const url = `${this.baseUrl}/${id}`;
    return this.http.delete<OfficeKey>(url).pipe(
      map((obj) => obj),
      catchError((e) => this.errorHandler(e))
    );
  }
```

But it is not working. I think I'm getting lost in the way Angular's architecture is built, how each thing connects and so on.
What am I doing wrong in this specific case?

Comment: Can you please copy that to stackblitz or copy the error that you get?

Comment: ```ERROR Error: Attempting to open an undefined instance of `mat-autocomplete`. Make sure that the id passed to the `matAutocomplete` is correct and that you're attempting to open it after the ngAfterContentInit hook.```

Also, the autocomplete is not working, when I type something nothing is suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mat-autocomplete has two parts: the input and the autoComplete itself. See that the "property" `matAutocomplete` make reference to a "template reference variable", (the #auto="matAutocomplete") in the first example of the docs:

```
<input ... [matAutocomplete]="auto">
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
</mat-autocomplete>
```

Not make reference to an array, else to a "component" of type AutoComplete

The options of mat-autocomplete is like (again the example of the docs)

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
  {{option}}
</mat-option>
```

See that it's used the [pipe async](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe). The pipe async work over an Observable. In general, this Observable is created using an Observable of the changes of the input. Here we have two options:

1.-use the operator map, to transform the value of the input in an array (filtering an array that we already loaded)

```
this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(
  startWith(''),
  map(value => this._filter(value)),
);
```

2.-Like you are trying to do using switchMap to return an observable -generally from a service-. but remember use the **pipe async**